# Add two simultaneous payment methods

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I need to be able  to select more than one payment method at the same time and that the order screen appears with the two or more selected methods.

Example image below.
[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, Iam still looking for :(

Comment: does seem to be to be a serious task, how about making it 300 points to get more traction?

Comment: No more points available.

Comment: Why you want to select multiple Payment Methods while checkout? At the end how many payment method you have. User is going to select only one payment method and do payment via that right? I am still not clear with concept or what you want to achieve